# Interleaving a fixed element into a given sequence of elements of a permutation group and the image of a point

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Let $G \le \operatorname{Sym}(n)$ be a permutation group on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. For $\alpha \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ and $x \in G$,
write $\alpha^x$ for the application of $x$ to $\alpha$. Fix some $g \in G$.

Define sequences $(h^{(i)}_1, \ldots, h^{(i)}_{m_i})$ for $i \ge 1$ by
choosing the first sequence
$$
 (h^{(1)}_1, \ldots, h^{(1)}_{m_1}) \in G^{m_i}
$$
and otherwise
$$
(h_1^{(i+1)}, \ldots, h_{m_i}^{(i+1)})
  = (h_1^{(i)}, \ldots, h_{j}^{(i)}, g, h_{j+1}^{(i)}, \ldots, h_{m_i}^{(i)})
$$
for some $j \in \{0, \ldots, m_i\}$, i.e., put the element $g$ somewhere in between. Then, does there exists an $N$ such that
$$
 1^{h_1^{(1)} \cdots h_{m_1}^{(1)}} = 1^{h_1^{(N)} \cdots h_{m_N}^{(N)}}?
$$
If $G$ is commutative, then $N = |G|$ will work. But does this hold in general?

Comment: When you write $(h_1^{(1)},\ldots,h_{m_1}^{(1)}) \in G$, do you really mean that each $h_i^{(1)} \in G$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes. Thank you; I fixed it by writing $\in G^{m_i}$ instead of $\in G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I have understood properly, but suppose $n=4$, $G=S_4$, and the starting sequence in $((1,2),(3,4))$. So the image of $1$ under this sequence is $2$.

Choose $g=(2,3)$ and change the sequence to $((1,2),g,(3,4)$, so the image of 1 is now $4$.

Thereafter, just insert $g$'s at the end of the sequence (or at the beginning if you prefer), giving sequences $((1,2),g,(3,4),g,g,g,g,g,\ldots)$, and the image of 1 remains 4.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was what I was asking for.